# how to post two values using functions in script tag?

Tags: php, html

**Here is my code****

Here is the code to post the selected value of drop downlist
   Here am trying to add the PHP date function to post that in url
   It is accepting the code written by me but it is not posting the value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function function2(select1)
    {
        var add = (select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value);
        var week= <?php date('W')+1 ?>;
        window.location = 'next.php?fname=' + add,'week='+week;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
window.location = 'next.php?fname=' + add +'&week='+week;
```

Comment: Aren't you still missing a `+` ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php echo date('W')+1; ?>;
```

and

```
window.location = 'next.php?fname=' + add + '&week='+week;
```